# Error while running Android emulator from command line

Tags: android, command-line, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am running an automated test and I have completed setting up the Android environment. After setting up the emulator one emulator is showing for the command **android list avd**. And following that when I try the command  **android avd** the following response is raising

```
Exception in thread "main" org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.createShell(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:163)
at com.android.sdkuilib.internal.repository.ui.AvdManagerWindowImpl1.open(AvdManagerWindowImpl1.java:134)
at com.android.sdkuilib.repository.AvdManagerWindow.open(AvdManagerWindow.java:94)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.showAvdManagerWindow(Main.java:438)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.doAction(Main.java:380)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.run(Main.java:151)
at com.android.sdkmanager.Main.main(Main.java:117)
```

I haven't installed any packages apart from the Android-Sdk. And all I need is to just run the emulator to install the apk and execute the acceptance test.